# what is good notification model?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

Hello everyone I am trying to build a notification model for my application but I dont know how to implement it. I have user, post, comment,like, follow system. I can do something with the model below but still lacks many functionality with it. I will be thankful if anyone can help me with this. :)

```js
var NotificationSchema = new Schema({
    Date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    },
    read: { 
        type: Boolean,
        default:false
    },
    userId: { 
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    message:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    postId:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'post'
    }
```

Comment: What kind of notification do you mean? I don´t understand why do you need a DB for the notifications

Comment: @fedeteka notification like : someone followed you , someone commented on your post and so on